# Font color of placeholder difference between Firefox 23.0.1 Chrome 23.0.1271.64 and IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I changed the placeholder font color of an input field to blue, I've tested it in Chrome, it's color is blue. But in FF 23.0.1, the color is slightly "lighter" than blue.

See the contrast below, note the "Month" is within a span and color is also blue:

In Chrome, it's fine, see below:

[image]

However, in firefox 23.0.1, looked like this:

[image]

In IE8, not display:

[image]

Note the difference of the color.

Below is the css code I am using:

```
.month_span { color: blue; }
.input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:blue}
.input::-moz-placeholder { color:blue; } /* FF 19+ */
.input:-moz-placeholder { color:#bbb; } /* FF 18- */
.input:-ms-input-placeholder { color:#bbb; }
```

My Question:1. Why the color is lighter in FF? 2. How to display placeholder value in IE?

Comment: Styling inputs is always a frustrating experience. Especially if you're trying to make them look the same across browsers. It's a valiant effort, but really, I wouldn't waste too much time on it.

Comment: Oh, I see you say IE8. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input), placeholder is only supported by IE10 and above.

Comment: Any reasons for the color difference do you think?

Comment: Maybe the text is greyed by the browser, after setting the color. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `placeholder` attribute isn't supported by IE until IE 10, so that explains that.

Firefox apparently applies `opacity:0.54` to the placeholder text:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/

This will fix:

```
.input::-moz-placeholder { color:blue; opacity: 1; } /* FF 19+ */
.input:-moz-placeholder { color:#bbb; opacity: 1; } /* FF 18- */
```

Comment: Thank you! This is useful! Solved!

Comment: note: currently the default opacity for the placeholder in FF is 0.4 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-moz-placeholder